Merging grid vectors that are touching one another in QGIS
As in the picture below, I am trying to merge the grids that are touching one another into a single polygon. I tried using the dissolve configuration on QGIS but it produced either 1) a vector polygon with just single observation or 2) replicates the exact grid vector with same number of observation.
From what I can imagine in the image below, the procedure should produce about 7 to 8 larger polygons and a few smaller ones.
In the past I did something similar but by using the GRASS Neighbor configuration and then polygonize the produced raster file but somehow I am unable to replicate the same thing with this exercise.
The purple grid each has a unique id and also contains the building (brown) coverage percentage for each grid.

The suggestions in response to my question seem to produce what I wanted. However, I do notice that there are some polygons that should be a single big polygon but instead are separated into smaller parts even though they are directly touching one another as shown below (lime green polygons).
Is there any way to fix this?


Dissolve, then multipart to singlepart

@MrXsquared Thank you!!

(You can also tick "Keep disjoint feature separate", then you dont need multipart to singleparts)

Polygons which share a single vertice cannot be dissolved and then exploded into "groups"; they will split themselves out.  You could try applying a very small positive buffer and then the same as a negative buffer but it might round corners more than you like.   As for the polygons that do appear to share a boundary but still remain separate, that usually happens if their boundaries aren't coincident, meaning every vertice in one polygon has a matched vertice in the adjoining one.  You could try a v.clean or snap to address those.

I appreciate the comments/notes and will give it a try. Thank you!
